# Is there an alternative to AtomicReferenceArray for large amounts of data?

Tags: java

I have a large amount of data that I'm currently storing in an `AtomicReferenceArray<X>`, and processing from a large number of threads concurrently.

Each element is quite small and I've just got to the point where I'm going to have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries. Unfortunately `List` and arrays in java are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or just less) values. Now I have enough memory to keep a larger structure in memory - with the machine having about 250GB of memory in a 64b VM.

Is there a replacement for `AtomicReferenceArray<X>` that is indexed by longs? (Otherwise I'm going to have to create my own wrapper that stores several smaller `AtomicReferenceArray` and maps long accesses to int accesses in the smaller ones.)

Comment: I wouldn't expect so.  (If you told us more about what you're doing we might be able to suggest an alternative solution.)

Comment: This is probably off-topic on grounds of "recommend a library", but what you need is off-heap data structures.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not clear, but I have 250GB+ memory in the machine. I want/need all the data in memory. If I do it myself I'll just have to create a wrapper class that wraps N of those `AtomicReferenceArray<X>` objects, each "large but not large enough".

Comment: Exceeding Integer.MAX_VALUE, a reference and the minimum overhead for one X will require close to 100GB. Are these 250GB+ "raw" byte counts? Or true Java object memory requirements?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE = (2*31-1)` and object reference is 8 bytes, this gives me 15G used for an array of `Integer.MaxValue` if entries are all null.

Comment: Agreed, but all the refs will eventually point to objects. I've calculated room for an empty object.

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml says that each object has an 8 byte header, so thats another 15GB if they're all non-null - still leaves 200GB of free memory for real object data. I'm sitting at about 20 bytes per object, which still leaves quite a bit of headroom. (Profiling memory usage through various methods gives values that match these quite closely)

Comment: The usual value one finds for a HotSpot JVM is 24 bytes. And take care to have just simple-typed fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it is time to use native memory.  Having 4+ billion objects is going to cause some dramatic GC pause times. However if you use native memory you can do this with almost no impact on the heap.  You can also use memory mapped files to support faster restarts and sharing the data between JVMs.

Not sure what your specific needs are but there are a number of open source data structures which do this like; [HugeArray](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/collection/HugeArray.java), [Chronicle Queue](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-queue/) and [Chronicle Map](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-map/) You can create an array which 1 TB but uses almost no heap and has no GC impact.

BTW For each object you create, there is a 8 byte reference and a 16 byte header.  By using native memory you can save 24 bytes per object e.g. 4 bn * 24 is 96 GB of memory.

Comment: This is a good answer - in that it sounds like these do the right thing. But it is expected that users add a disclaimer or note when they're associated with an application/product/library that they're recommending.